# How can I clear the scrollback buffer in konsole from bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, script, konsole

I'm a heavy bash user and konsole is my preferred environment. I know I can use the keyboard command ctrl+shift+x to clear the scrollback buffer, but there's certain points in my scripts where I would like that to occur. How can I clear konsole's scrollback buffer using the command line, bash, or any other shell?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will do it:

```
echo -e "\e[3J"
```

Found [here](http://lists.kde.org/?l=konsole-devel&m=120370129202743&w=2).  Works in regular xterm too.

Comment: nice! good find and works perfectly!

Comment: didn't work for me on SUSE in a xterm with bash shell.

Comment: I liked echo -ne "\e[3J" better as it avoids printed line-break.

Comment: @PatricB.: true, though in this context, I'm expecting him to incorporate it into a script

Comment: @PatrickB. Thanks for the reminder on the -n. :)

Comment: Doesn't work on Kubuntu 14.04.02

Comment: @SandeepDatta: It works with konsole 4.14.3 on Fedora 20; it doesn't clear the screen--it clears the scrollback buffer.

Comment: As an extension to this answer, I aliased this to the clear command (`alias clear="clear && echo -e '\e[3J' && clear"`) so my screen actually clears now.

Comment: Doesn't work anymore with Konsole version 21.12.3.